# Active Directory properties for Mailing Address

Tags: active-directory

The Active Directory properties currently used at the customer's site for the users's business addresses are: streetAddress, l, st, postalCode, co.

Which properties can I use to store their "mailing" addresses? This type of address can be seen as a secondary home address.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend to use for that purpose attribute

```
homePostalAddress
```

In general you can check all available Active Directory attributes and their usage in Active Directory Schema documentation for attributes https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675090(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: I tried using the postalAddress:     SELECT cn, employeeID, postalAddress FROM OpenQuery(ADSI,'SELECT cn, employeeID, manager, postalAddress FROM ''LDAP://...'' WHERE objectClass = ''User'' AND employeeID=123') and I get the error "Cannot get the data of the row from the OLE DB provider "ADSDSOObject" for linked server "ADSI". Could not convert the data value due to reasons other than sign mismatch or overflow." I tried to fill in those values programmatically. Are there any restrictions e.g. size?

Comment: homePostalAddress worked and postalAddress didn't because the OLE DB provider can only read attributes defined to have single values only. homePostalAddress  Is-Single-Valued  true!